# Why is the page constantly waiting?

Tags: web, browser, html

For some reason, my pages continue to load forever even though it appears it is done. How do I look to see what resource is being "waited upon"?

This page is one with the problem.

http://www.cadwolf.com/Documents/Documentation/Users_Guide_-_Tables

Comment: I went to it and it loaded just fine in IE, Firefox, and Chrome

Comment: Look at the network tab in the dev tools.

Comment: OK, the page loads differently depending on the permissions you have. It appears that it works fine for a normal load. I have looked under the network tab, but I am not sure exactly what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The page loads fine for me as well, but if you want to see what is being loaded or if there are errors you can check your developers tool. (Press f12 in google chrome). From there you can click on the network tab or the console tab.

Editing here cause I can't comment yet: In the network tab you can see everything that's being loaded for your page. So in the status column, it should say 200 OK to show your resources are loading properly. Here, you can see if something is being held up and what it is.